# Change the way Jovie speaks time

Tags: kde

Is there a way to edit the text Jovie reads to speak time.
For example it says *"It is 2:00 O clock"*. How can I change it to *"local time 2:00 o'clock"*?

Or how can I  change *"It is twenty three O clock"* to *"It is 11:00 PM"*?

Comment: That sound like a good idea, have you considered posting it to http://forum.kde.org/ ?

Comment: not yet‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.